# No Audio for videos in android-youtubeExtractor when download video with quality 1080p

Tags: android, download

No Audio for videos in android-youtubeExtractor for 1080p
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqfkw.png)

Comment: This question is not about programming.

Comment: My question for programming because I use youtubeExtractor library for downloading video from my app

Comment: Okay! Its better to post a detailed question like library link, some code and some test results like the codec of the video

Comment: If issue is related to a custom library than instead of posting question here open up issue on `Github` or from place you have downloaded library.

Comment: this is the link of library and code in a GitHub https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor